# How can I print a multiple line status message?

Tags: cmake

Consider the following example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(TEST)

set(msg "line1\nline2\nline3")
message(STATUS ${msg})
```

This gives the following output:

```
-- line1
line2
line3
```

How can I print the message as multiple line status:

```
-- line1
-- line2
-- line3
```

I tried to use string replace without success:

```
set(msg "line1\nline2\nline3")
string(REPLACE "\n" "\n-- " ${msg} ${msg})
message(STATUS ${msg})
```

Comment: `message(STATUS line1) message(STATUS line2) messaget(STATUS line3)` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk The string is provided by a 3rd party, but this suggestion would also work. For that I would have to split the lines and loop through them to print as messages. I prefer Fred's answer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ cat ml.cmake
set(msg "line1\nline2\nline3")
string(REPLACE "\n" "\n-- " msg ${msg})
message(STATUS ${msg})

$ cmake -P ml.cmake
-- line1
-- line2
-- line3
```

Comment: can you explain why my approach did not work? The syntax is `string(REPLACE <match-string> <replace-string> <out-var> <input>...)`. Looking at samples I can see both variants.

Comment: Your original syntax is wrong.  You didn't specify `<out-var>` as `msg`, but as `${msg}` which is then expanded and creates a new variable called `line1\nline2\nline3`.  You can even use this variable but it will also print a warning message for weird variable names.